# Problems with java physics simulation function

Tags: java

I am creating this physics simulation that is supposed to simulate the movement of celestial bodies in space on a 2D plane. It is very basic. It is not supposed to be very intensive. However, after five or six seconds, the objects disappear, let alone that they don't move properly. I have been looking at this for too long and would appreciate fresh eyes to take a look at it. I just need to know why the points disappear after five-six seconds. Don't worry if the math is wrong, I can fix that after I find out why the stars vanish. Please disregard any poor programming, I haven't been programming for very long.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class PhysicsSimulation extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
private JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
private JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
private boolean running = false;
private boolean paused = false;
private int fps = 60;
private int frameCount = 0;

public PhysicsSimulation()
{
    super("Fixed Timestep Game Loop Test");
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p.add(startButton);
    p.add(pauseButton);
    p.add(quitButton);
    cp.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    cp.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(800, 800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    quitButton.addActionListener(this);
    pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PhysicsSimulation phy = new PhysicsSimulation();
    phy.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object s = e.getSource();
    if (s == startButton)
    {
        running = !running;
        if (running)
        {
            startButton.setText("Stop");
            runGameLoop();
        }
        else
        {
            startButton.setText("Start");
        }
    }
    else if (s == pauseButton)
    {
        paused = !paused;
        if (paused)
        {
            pauseButton.setText("Unpause");
        }
        else
        {
            pauseButton.setText("Pause");
        }
    }
    else if (s == quitButton)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void runGameLoop()
{
    Thread loop = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            gameLoop();
        }
    };
    loop.start();
}

private void gameLoop()
{
    final double GAME_HERTZ = 30.0;
    final double TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000000000 / GAME_HERTZ;
    final int MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER = 5;
    double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
    double lastRenderTime = System.nanoTime();

    final double TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final double TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;

    int lastSecondTime = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);

    while (running)
    {
        double now = System.nanoTime();
        int updateCount = 0;

        if (!paused)
        {
            while( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES && updateCount < MAX_UPDATES_BEFORE_RENDER )
            {
                updateGame();
                lastUpdateTime += TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
                updateCount++;
            }

            if ( now - lastUpdateTime > TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
            {
                lastUpdateTime = now - TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES;
            }

            float interpolation = Math.min(1.0f, (float) ((now - lastUpdateTime) / TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES) );
            drawGame(interpolation);
            lastRenderTime = now;

            int thisSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / 1000000000);
            if (thisSecond > lastSecondTime)
            {
                System.out.println("NEW SECOND " + thisSecond + " " + frameCount);
                fps = frameCount;
                frameCount = 0;
                lastSecondTime = thisSecond;
            }

            while ( now - lastRenderTime < TARGET_TIME_BETWEEN_RENDERS && now - lastUpdateTime < TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES)
            {
                Thread.yield();

                try {Thread.sleep(1);} catch(Exception e) {}

                now = System.nanoTime();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void updateGame()
{
    gamePanel.update();
}

private void drawGame(float interpolation)
{
    gamePanel.setInterpolation(interpolation);
    gamePanel.repaint();
}

private class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    float interpolation;
    ArrayList<Star> list = new ArrayList<Star>();
    double G = .00000000006674;

    public GamePanel()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            list.add(i,new Star());
        }
    }

    public void setInterpolation(float interp)
    {
        interpolation = interp;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            list.get(i).setX(list.get(i).getLastX()+list.get(i).getXVelocity());
            list.get(i).setY(list.get(i).getLastY()+list.get(i).getYVelocity());
            for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
                if(j != i){
                    if(list.get(i).getX() == list.get(j).getX() && list.get(i).getY() == list.get(j).getY()){
                        list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity()));
                        list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity()));
                    }
                    else{
                        list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),0)));
                        list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),1)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public float calcVelocity(Star a, Star b, int var){
        double velocity = 0;
        velocity = (double) Math.pow(((2*G*a.getMass()*b.getMass()*delta(a,b,var))/(Math.pow(delta(a,b,var),2)*a.getMass())),.5);
        return (float) velocity;
    }

    public float delta(Star a, Star b, int var){
        float diff = 0;
        if(var == 0)
            diff = Math.abs(a.getX()-b.getX());
        else if(var == 1)
            diff = Math.abs(a.getY()-b.getY());
        return diff;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,800,740);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            g.fillRect((int)list.get(i).getX(),(int)list.get(i).getY(),1,1);
        }

        g.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 5, 10);

        frameCount++;
    }
}

private class Star{
    float x, y, lastX, lastY;
    float xVelocity, yVelocity;
    float mass;

    public Star(){
        x = (float) (Math.random() * 800);
        y = (float) (Math.random() * 740);
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
        xVelocity = 0;
        yVelocity = 0;
        mass = (float) (Math.random() * 800000000);
    }

    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public float getXVelocity(){
        return xVelocity;
    }

    public float getYVelocity(){
        return yVelocity;
    }

    public float getMass(){
        return mass;
    }

    public float getLastX(){
        return lastX;
    }

    public float getLastY(){
        return lastY;
    }

    public void setX(float X){
        x = X;
    }

    public void setY(float Y){
        y = Y;
    }

    public void setXVelocity(float velocity){
        xVelocity = velocity;
    }

    public void setYVelocity(float velocity){
        yVelocity = velocity;
    }

    public void setLastX(float X){
        lastX = X;
    }

    public void setLastY(float Y){
        lastY = Y;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger and/or output statements to help narrow down where the problem occurs?

Comment: When I output the x and y coordinates in command prompt, it just suddenly becomes NaN.

Comment: If you say the objects disappear, look at the code that draws the objects. Look at what that code depends on and whether the input to the drawing code could be messed up after 5 seconds. Hence unable to draw the objects properly.

Comment: NaN points to possible division by 0. I would check the formula of calculation x and y and see whether division by 0 is possible.

Comment: Are you sure your `getVelocity` method is calculating velocity, not acceleration?

Comment: Thanks. I added a few more if statements and the stars don't disappear anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more clearly what you did to fix the problem, and post it as an answer, for the benefit of future users of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to you all, I figured out that I needed to add a few more if statements to handle when the distance was zero.

Original:

```
if(list.get(i).getX() == list.get(j).getX() && list.get(i).getY() == list.get(j).getY()){
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity()));
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity()));
}
else{
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),0)));
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),1)));
}
```

Revised:

```
if(list.get(i).getX() == list.get(j).getX()){
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity())+1);
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),1)));
}
else if(list.get(i).getY() == list.get(j).getY()){
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity())+1);
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),0)));
}
else if(list.get(i).getX() == list.get(j).getX() && list.get(i).getY() == list.get(j).getY()){
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity())+1);
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity())+1);
}
else{
    list.get(i).setXVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getXVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),0)));
    list.get(i).setYVelocity((float) (list.get(i).getYVelocity() + calcVelocity(list.get(i),list.get(j),1)));
}
```